# Writing a "dynamic" formula in a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

The cell is not filled with the formula, but a "FALSE" is written in there. Any ideas how to change that, so that the formula is displayed correctly? No error message though..

```
'code
q = 1
Do Until q = 10
   q = q + 1
   If Cells(q, 4).HasFormula Then
   Else
     If IsEmpty(Cells(q, 4)) Then
     Cells(q, 4).Formula = Cells(q, 4).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E" & q & ",Lagerplätze!A:B,2,FALSE),)"
     End If
   End If
Loop

'code
```

EDIT: updated code

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean with "it isn't working properly"? Does it throw an error? It doesn't do anything? It does something, but not what you expected?

Comment: i hope it's clearer now

Comment: can you type the exact formula that you are trying to put. I mean how would you have entered in an Excel Cell

Comment: done that, look at the edit

Comment: Your VBA is referencing `D` but your excel formula is referencing `E`?

Comment: but, unfortunately it still doesnt work.. i adapted it, but now, nothing is wrote down in the cell

Comment: can you explain what exactly are you doing? where are you putting the first formula?

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything

Comment: maybe EDIT2 in the original post is describing it a little bit better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Formula property requires you to use US regional settings, so:

```
Cells(q, 5).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E" & q & ",Lagerplätze!A:B,2,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(E" & q & ",Lagerplätze!A:B,2,FALSE)"
```

Also, if you're using Excel 2007 or later, I'd suggest IFERROR:

```
Cells(q, 5).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E" & q & ",Lagerplätze!A:B,2,FALSE),"""")
```

Comment: thanks, that was definitely one of the mistakes! but still, the cell isn't showing the formula like it's supposed to, but only a "FALSE"..

Comment: Just noticed you are putting the formula in column E, but you're also looking up column E. You can't do that - it creates a circular reference.

Comment: thats not the problem, it is supposed to fill D, by looking up column E. typo; i updated the code

Comment: You adjusted the code wrongly and doubled up the `Cells(q, 4).Formula = ` part!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the & character to concatenate the formula's text with the q variable

```
 Cells(q, 4).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D" & q & ";Lagerplätze!A:B;2;FALSE));"""";VLOOKUP(D" & q & ";Lagerplätze!A:B;2;FALSE))"
```

Edit: Added missing closing bracket.

Comment: @SiddharthRout  ... and I even know what `Lagerplätze` is without consulting a dictionary :-))

Comment: @KaChiing: Replace "D" with "E"

Comment: thanks for the hint, but it still tells me I got an objectrelated error

Comment: The IF statement is missing a closing bracket. It did in your original code and I did not catch it, because I was distracted by the missing `&` operator.